My C++ Code is not running in vs code and I have already save this code it still shows collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
My C++ Code is not running in vs code and I have already save this code it still shows collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
This is the error it showing
I had already installed the c++ microsoft extension and code runner but still code is not working .

Do not post images instead of code. SO is literally built to be able to format code and error message. Please see how to ask.

Why are you using MingW instead of MSVC? How are you configuring and linking to the compiler?
